# Index match function not working for lookup values that are also in the lookup array

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a workbook where I am trying to match each employee's name with their supervisor's name. Data for each employee including their supervisor's name is stored in a sheet called 'AllData'. I then have a sheet called 'Total' where my Index/match formula is.

So far the formula below is working. Except it is returning 0.00 for any employees whose name also appears in the supervisor's name column of the sheet 'AllData'. Therefore, it is almost like index/match doesn't work when the lookup value is also in the lookup array.

Does anyone know a way around this, or if I am doing something wrong?

```
=INDEX(AllData!B7:B950,MATCH(Totals!C7,AllData!E:E,0))
```

Thanks.

Comment: The INDEX and MATCH ranges aren't the same size.  Maybe the MATCH range should be `AllData!E7:E950`?

Comment: I agree with @Domenic, issue could be with range. My guess is that MATCH returns a value higher than 943 which is out of range for B7:B950, so it returns 0.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example for you.

your formula is right but you have to enter array **(<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>enter</kbd>)**
**{=INDEX(AllData!B7:B950,MATCH(Totals!C7,AllData!E:E,0))}**

You can try the below steps which can help easier. There is no matching for **Column reference**, please change the below type of method.

[image]

The view is **Total** Sheet, In the **AllData** Sheet "A:A = Employee Names" and "B:B = Supervisor Name".

Formula Used In **C2*

**=INDEX(AllData!$A$1:$B$11,MATCH($B2,AllData!$A:$A),MATCH(C$1,AllData!$A$1:$B$1))**